# Are AVR chips open source?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr

I am working on a new product, hoping to start up my company with it. I'm an electronics noob. I want to know whether AVR microcontrollers are open source, and if I use them, should my product be open source as well? Because Arduino also uses an AVR chip and its schematics are open.

Comment: If you don't take your question seriously enough write it properly, then there is no reason for us to take is seriously either.  -1 for thumbing your nose at all the volunteers here.  I quit reading about halfway thru when it became clear that continuing trying to decode the runon sentence would be too annoying, so closing as *unclear*.

Comment: If you are an electronics noob, I hope that you will hire someone to design the product that will be produced by your start up your company, sure?

Answer (score 9):

No, AVR chips are definitely NOT open-source. However, that doesn't imply anything at all about whether a product you build using them can or cannot be open-source.

Arduino is open-source, but there are thousands, if not millions of commercial products that use the same chips that are completely proprietary.

Comment: Just to add an example, there are probably millions of open-source projects running on Intel X86 chips which are the exact opposite of open source.

Answer (score 3):

AVR is proprietary.

It can be programmed using open-source tools like avr-gcc and avrdude (both work great) but using these tools does not mean you have to opensource your code.

> arduino also uses an avr chip and its schematics are open.

This is a choice made by the arduino creators, you don't have to do the same choice.

What would force your code to be open-source would be using code that is under a licence like GPL. So please check the licensing requirements of code and libraries you use.

Answer (score 0):

> "should my product be open source as well because arduino also uses an
>   avr chip"

No.  Unless you use designs or codes, in part or in whole, that are covered by a license demanding so.

If you use your own design, and don't steal anyone's licensed code that prohibits use, then you own it and you can do as you please.

There are always lawyer-ly details.  If you're concerned about that type of thing, then hire a lawyer, and don't trust strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

AVR's code is proprietary, but are licensed for your use by Atmel.  You are allowed to distribute your commercial product using their code by Atmel's license.  No open sourcing is required.

Arduino code is open sourced, but using open source does not always compel you to open source your product.  There are licenses which do this (they're nicknamed "copyleft" licenses), But the Arduino does not use these licenses.  From [their FAQ](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ):

> Open-source hardware shares much of the principles and approach of free and open-source software. In particular, we believe that people should be able to study our hardware to understand how it works, make changes to it, and share those changes. To facilitate this, we release all of the original design files (Eagle CAD) for the Arduino hardware. **These files are licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike license, which allows for both personal and commercial derivative works**, as long as they credit Arduino and release their designs under the same license. The Arduino software is also open-source. The source code for the Java environment is released under the GPL and the **C/C++ microcontroller libraries are under the LGPL.** (emphasis mine)

They state explicitly that their original design files are licensed in a way that permits commercial works.  This means you could take their schematics, modify them, and produce a commercial work from them.  However, in your case, you are almost certainly not selling schematics.  You're using existing AVR chips made by a foundry.  This part of the license won't be important for you.

What will be important is that the C/C++ libraries are LGPL-ed.  The LGPL license is written *explicitly* to permit you to use these libraries inside a commercial closed-source application.  So thus you can be confident that you do not need to open source your product.

Comment: This seems to be basically correct, if a little confusing. I don't understand what "code" you're talking about in the first paragraph.

Comment: @DaveTweed Header files, compiled libraries, etc.  Basically all of the software that gets bundled with your product when you deploy it.  I actually don't know what the licensing is on the AVR hardware, but I presume that it's designed to ... you know... be used, so it's probably licensed correctly =)

Comment: Ah. But it's always possible to develop software for an AVR product without ever touching any Atmel software. There are plenty of third-party toolchains and libraries available. In any case, licensing of the software is a completely separate issue from the chip (hardware design) itself, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: _"AVR's code is proprietary, but are licensed for your use by Atmel. You are allowed to distribute your commercial product using their code by Atmel's license."_ - Atmel Studio uses [avg-gcc](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/atmelstudio/atmelstudio.section.kcg_dse_lc.html), which is GPL-licensed, and [avr-libc](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/atmelstudio/avrtoolchain.Projects.GCC_projectOptions.CompilerOptions.html), which is BSD-licensed. _"All of the software that gets bundled with your product when you deploy it"_ is fully open source, nothing proprietary about it.

Comment: *"the C/C++ microcontroller libraries are under the LGPL"*. There are some that don't use the LGPL license: [Arduino AVR Boards core library](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/cores/arduino) files: CDC.cpp (ISC), USBCore (ISC), USBDesc.h (ISC), Udp.h (MIT). Libraries bundled with Arduino AVR Boards: [HID](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/libraries/HID/src/HID.h) (ISC). Libraries bundled with the Arduino IDE: [SD](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/SD) (GPL), [Temboo](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Temboo) (Apache).